# Increasing URL parameter based on previous parameter value

Tags: php, url, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to increase a count passed conditional on a link. My page is set up as follows:

URL Parameter = `?c=10`
basecount = `$base_count = 10;`

My code is set up as follows:

```
$base_count = 10;
$add = $_REQUEST['c'];
$count = $base_count + $add;

<div class="news_outlet_loadmore">
    <h2><a id="load-more" href="?c=5">Load more</a></h2>
</div>
```

This currently expands the allowed results by 5 but I need to allow it to compound the results each time so on the next reload `?c=10` and then `?c=15` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo out the changed value with something like this:

```
$base_count = 10;
$add = $_REQUEST['c'];
$count = $base_count + $add;

<div class="news_outlet_loadmore">
    <h2><a id="load-more" href="?c=<?php echo ($add+5)?>">Load more</a></h2>
</div>
```

It should be cumulative because you're requesting the querystring value for "c" then adding 5 to it and sending it back as "c" again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a $_SESSION variable to store the value instead of using a $_GET variable. The Session variables are stored in the server and are different for each user connected (so, in the following example, every user will have their own $_SESSION["foo"]).

So you could use:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION["foo"])){
   $_SESSION["foo"] = 0;    
}else{
   $_SESSION["foo"]+=5;
}
echo $_SESSION["foo"];
?>
```

So, this way every time the user refreshes the page the foo value will go up by five.